Is this enough calculation on server-side to be secure?
I'm a beginner about client/server calculations and relationships (never trust the client), and I would like to know if I did or didn't get the concept right.
My weapons are calling this function inside their OnTriggerEnter2D:
[Rpc(SendTo.Server, RequireOwnership = false)]
public void TakeDamageServerRpc()
{
    //Calculate damage and stuff


    //then send to Rpc client
    TakeDamageClientRpc(1, RpcTarget.Single(OwnerClientId, RpcTargetUse.Temp));
}

This means the damage calculation (here it just sends 1) is done on the servers; afterwards, I call the function on the corresponding client side which looks like this:
[Rpc(SendTo.SpecifiedInParams)]
private void TakeDamageClientRpc(int damage, RpcParams rpcParams = default)
{
    if (state == STATE.DEAD)
        return;

    if (damage >= 1)
        state = STATE.DEAD;
}

My questions here are :

Is the state variable on the player safe here? (I'd say yes.)
Can the integer damage sent to the client be manipulated? (I'd say no.)
Should TakeDamageServerRpc have an entry variable, can I trust it? (I'd say no.)



Is wrong. Changing states of objects is trusting the client. Depending on what that object does, nothing would prevent the client from keeping it alive or setting it dead. The question does not state how state is synced, because as your code is right now, this seems to be a client variable. You should not use rpc for changing values, use NetworkVariable. In your example you should change the state already in TakeDamageServerRpc, state gets synced via NetworkVariable to all clients and TakeDamageClientRpc is used to play like a hurt animation on the client. See further information in the docu

Is wrong. You could theoretically inject into the method your own function that relies that the function gets triggered from the server but you overwrite any values it provides. This would affect only the client that does the manipulation. You can trust that the 1 is sent to the client, you can not trust the client that it will act accordingly on that 1 dmg. How much that helps/ achieves in your game is a different matter.

Correct, you should not trust the client with absolut values in network games. For example in a card battle game, instead of doing Fireball deals 5 damage to card X you should code it like: Using card Fireball on target X. The server can now verify that:



You have Fireball available
You can actually use/ cast/ pay the cost
Your target is available
Calculate the dmg
Reduce mana/ energy/ charges/ HP
Remove used card
Notify client of result and let it play fancy animation/ update values


Thanks, I'm going to need to sleep on that, but basically it looks like 95%+ of the Rpc actions will be done by the server and synced with Network Transforms/Variables/Objects with the clients

Depends on the type of your game, I would say it is more 50:50 - the client wants to do something and the server responds. But a board game would have a different ratio compared to an MMO compared to a shooter

For #2, the value from the server could be modified with an injected function, or with a separate application that intercepts and modifies the incoming packets.

If I'm understanding the premise correctly, there is also an unstated assumption #0 which is also wrong. TakeDamageServer should not be an RPC call in the first place, because then there's nothing stopping a malicious client from calling that method to deal damage to whatever they want dead, anywhere in the world, no weapons hitting the target required.

@Kevin but thats what I wrote in the answer. Maybe I should write it a bit more clearly

@TimC I'm not so familiar with the Unity networking annotation (more using MIrror myself), but I would assume that [Rpc(SendTo.Server, RequireOwnership = false)] is the correct way to call the server function part (the counterpart in mirror would be called command)

@Zibelas Your answer says "inject into the method your own function", which sounds like modifying the client application (the game). My point was that a player could also cheat by using a separate application to intercept and modify the packets, without injecting code into or otherwise modifying the game itself.

@TimC the TakeDamageServerRpc() is called through a OnTriggerEnter2D which I think can be run on both client or server, so i have to limit the rest of the calculations to the server.

@Jime - If OnTriggerEnter2D runs on the client and calls TakeDamageServerRpc(), then that means that the client can call TakeDamageServerRpc() - and that it can call that method whenever it wants, with whatever arguments it wants, and the server will dutifully apply that method wherever asked. The security inside of the method doesn't matter, since the client can already arbitrarily tell the server to deal damage to anything.


I'm a beginner ... ... (never trust the client)

Saying "never" kinda puts you in a box, it's probably better to say "how/when" should the server trust the client. The way you trust your client is going to be dependent on game you are creating, taking two examples from opposite ends of the spectrum:
Online Chess
You can/should check each move is valid (conforms to the rules of chess) on both the client and server. So for the most part you can do any move animations on the client. Some rules probably don't make any sense in online chess such as "if you touch a piece you have to move it", hence the solution is simply to abandon that rule.
However one place where you may want the server to be authoritative is the move clock. In that you probably want to use the moment the server receives the move to, change which players clock is counting down. This could mean that a player thinks they got their move in before the time ran out, however the move didn't get to the server in time.
You can minimize the likelihood of this occurring by accounting for the network latency / trying to synchronize the remaining game time between the client and server (server is authoritative). But you may also want to allow the client to submit a move to the server after the local clock has run out (since only the server is authoritative).
Obviously in online chess, the most likely cheat is using an engine to calculate moves - however thats not really a client/server issue so I have not discussed it.
First Person Shooter
It would "theoretically" be possible to take all input from the user, send that to the server return the new position information from the server and then render the frame to the user. However as a practical matter that would either result in huge input lag and/or single digit frame rates.
So as a practical matter the server has to "somewhat" trust the position of the player (as reported by the client), however this a bounded trust:

The player has a maximum movement speed - that the server can verify.
The player typically cannot move up (more than a specific jump height).
The player cannot teleport through walls (hence cannot get to the other side without the required time to walk around the wall)

For hitscan/raycast weapons you again have to trust the client, that the player actually made the shot, however again there are things you can check/mitigate:

Was the shot possible - given the viable positions of both players (and location of cover) - given their movement speeds?
How much damage did the player do - given the weapon choice and known rate of fire?
You probably don't want the client to even calculate the damage - send details of the type of shot (weapon type + damage location) to the server and have the server calculate the damage.

Riot wrote a blog about some of these issues I will specifically point you to the section on: "Resolving combat on the server"
https://technology.riotgames.com/news/peeking-valorants-netcode
